# MVC 5 dropdown value when selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a category and sub category dropdown list in my view. I select the items in the DDL and submit. In my controller I can only see the categoryID, subCategoryID values for the DDL. I need to get the selected text values (categoryName, subCategoryName). In winforms it is known as the DisplayMember.

I can get the categoryName, subcategoryName values if I run a query based on the returned ID, but this feels like I'm hitting the database more times than I need to.

Here is my code:

ViewModel

```
public class MedicalCategoryVM
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> RowGuid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public List<MedicalCategory> MedicalCategories { get; set; }
```

}

View:

```html
@model DofE.Models.MedicalCategoryVM
<br />
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        @Html.Label("Medical Information", new { style = "font-size:16px; background-color:#002142; color:white;margin-left:10px" })



        <div class="form-group">
 
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, new SelectList(Model.MedicalCategories,"CategoryID","CategoryName"),"--Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
             
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubCategoryID, new SelectList(""), "--Select Sub Category", new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div style="padding-left:340px">
                <span style="display: inline;">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" }) &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
                </span>
            </div>
            @*<div class="test">
                    <div style="float: right;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>

                </div>*@


        </div>
    </div>
}
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CategoryID").change(function () {
                $.get("/MedicalHistory/GetSubCategoryList", { CategoryID: $("#CategoryID").val() }, function (data) {
                    $("#SubCategoryID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#SubCategoryID").append("<option value='" + row.SubCategoryID + "'>" + row.SubCategoryName + "</option>")
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {

        MedicalCategoryVM CategoryVM = new MedicalCategoryVM();
        CategoryVM.MedicalCategories = db.MedicalCategories.ToList();
        //ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(CategoryList, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");


        return View(CategoryVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersonID,CategoryName,SubCategoryName,Notes,RowGuid,ModifiedDate")] MedicalHistory medicalHistory, FormCollection form)
    {
        //string catName = form["CategoryName"].ToString();
        //string subCatName = form["SubCategoryName"].ToString();
        int catID = Convert.ToInt16(form["CategoryID"]);
        int subCatID = Convert.ToInt16(form["SubCategoryID"]);
        MedicalSubCategory cat = db.MedicalSubCategories.Find(subCatID);

        medicalHistory.CategoryName = cat.CategoryName;
        medicalHistory.SubCategoryName=cat.SubCategoryName;
        medicalHistory.RowGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        medicalHistory.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MedicalHistories.Add(medicalHistory);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(medicalHistory);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the Id in the `MedicalHistory` model also?

Comment: Medical History is a table in the database where the PersonID, CategoryName,SubCategoryName, Notes and ModifiedDate is saved. The ID in MedicalHistory is auto generated upon insertion of a record. My intention was to grab the selected dropdown list text and include it in the controller.